# XSL-FO Table of Contents page number left aligned when page title is too long

Tags: xsl-fo, page-numbering

We are using this XSL-FO to generate entries in the Table of Contents page:

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />
    <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{@id}" />
</fo:block>
```

When pages have very long titles, the page number is bumped onto a new line. If the page title is long enough to bump the page number onto a new line *but not* long enough to go onto a new line itself, the page number will be left aligned when it should be right aligned.

As far as I can tell, the XML is correct and this is an issue with XSL-FO itself. Is there a way to get all of the page numbers right aligned without redesigning anything else about the layout?

[image: image of table of contents where the page titles have different lengths and the middle length has a left-aligned page number]

**Update:**

Thanks for the response Tony Graham, unfortunately it doesn't seem for me for some reason. On lines that should have a single continuous leader I would end up with two sets of leader dots separated by a small gap that I could not get rid of. But it did inspire this solution that works well enough for me:

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />
    <fo:page-number-citation keep-with-previous="always" ref-id="{@id}" />
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Which software are you using to generated to PDF? If you're using Antenna House Formatter, it has extensions to handle this case : https://www.docs.antennahouse.com/formatter/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion

Comment: It will not possible to resolve this case unless formatter you are using supports forcing fo:leader to expanse unconditionally such like above example page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have examples 1, 3, and 5 from the `axf:leader-expansion` documentation at https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion

As others have pointed out, you can't handle every possible ToC or index variant with vanilla XSL-FO, but you can achieve a result for the sample that you showed:

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"
     leader-alignment="reference-area"
     text-align-last="justify">
  <fo:block>Page with very short title<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" /><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />3</fo:block>
  <fo:block>Page with very very very very very very very very long title<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" /><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />4</fo:block>
  <fo:block>Page with very very very very very very very very very very very very long title<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" keep-with-previous.within-line="always" /><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />5</fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

[image: Formatted ToC]

Tested with AH Formatter V7.0.